# Inheritance mapping in Doctrine

Tags: php, database, doctrine

I'd like to use inheritance relationships in Doctrine but I cannot make it work.

Here is my parent entity :

```
<?php
namespace My\Entire\Workspace;

/**
 * Class MyClass
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="my_class")
 */
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Target", inversedBy="...")
     * @JoinColumn(name="target_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $target;

    /**
     * @Column(type="text", name="`value`")
     */
    protected $value;

}
```

Where Target is in the same namespace (My\Entire\Workspace). I'v not mentioned the get/set methods. This entity is on one of my project located in the vendor/... directory.

And now the child entity :

```
<?php
namespace My\Namespace;

use My\Entire\Namespace\MyClass as LMyClass;

/**
 * Class MyClass
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="my_class")
 */
class MyClass extends LMyClass
{
}
```

You can see that the classes have the same name (MyClass) but are in different namespaces. The child class have nothing in it and won't have anything in the first version of my project.

When I'm doing `doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql` it creates me the two tables (targets and my_class) but in my_class it create only the string field 'value' but not the target_id one.

I'v tried a lot of things i've read in the doc (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) but nothing worked so far.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What kind of inheritance do you want to implement? Your example does not match any of the supported once.

Comment: I'd like to do a single table inheritance.

Comment: You are completely missing the `Annotations` `@InheritanceType` and `@DiscriminatorColumn` mentioned in the  [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance). Maybe this is the root cause of your issue?

Comment: Yes I have seen that in the doc but I don't want to put these annotations in the parent project. It would not make sense.